# Typescript compiler type assignment error ignored

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, tsconfig

I have the following scenario:

```
const customer = new Customer();
let customerViewModel = new CustomerLayoutViewModel();

customerViewModel = customer;
```

This does not produce an error when compiled which in my mind is the wrong behaviour. This seems to be due to the fact that `Customer` and `CustomerLayoutViewModel` are completely identical.

The problem is that over time they will not be identical and I want the above code to give a compile error because the types are different.

So my question: How do I configure the compiler to produce an error in the above example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript uses structural typing when determining type compatibility. This means that if the two types have a compatible structure they will be compatible:

```
class Customer { name: string }
class CustomerLayoutViewModel { name: string }
const customer = new Customer();
let customerViewModel = new CustomerLayoutViewModel();
customerViewModel = customer; // OK compatible
```

If `Customer` has extra properties the types are still compatible, there is no chance someone will access through `customerViewModel` something that isn't there:

```
class Customer { name: string; fullName: string }
class CustomerLayoutViewModel { name: string }
const customer = new Customer();
let customerViewModel = new CustomerLayoutViewModel();
customerViewModel = customer; // still OK compatible
```

You will get compatibility errors if `CustomerLayoutViewModel` has extra required properties:

```
class Customer { name: string }
class CustomerLayoutViewModel { name: string; fullName: string }
const customer = new Customer();
let customerViewModel = new CustomerLayoutViewModel();
customerViewModel = customer; //error now
```

The one way to ensure types are incompatible it to add a private field to a class. private fields will not be compatible with any other field in any other class event if the name is the same:

```
class Customer { private x: string }
class CustomerLayoutViewModel { private x: string }
const customer = new Customer();
let customerViewModel = new CustomerLayoutViewModel();
customerViewModel = customer; //error Types have separate declarations of a private property 'x'.
```

Comment: But doing that is not a solution for me - I have to configure(if possible) the compiler so that this scenario gives a compile error.

Comment: @Diemauerdk not possible, this is a fundamental way the type system works. The private property has no runtime impact if unassigned, it's the closest you will get to normative typing in typescript

Comment: Okay, but that sucks. I have a background as C# developer, so I guess I still carry that bag with me :) In my opinion, it's a bug but I guess it's by design then. I had hoped that I could configure a more strict behaviour that would catch this, for example in tsconfig. Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: @Diemauerdk for simple classes you will probably get unwanted compatibilities usually as the class grows these become less of an issue. I have a  C# background and it is an adjustment I agree :)

Answer (score 0):

This will not give compile error because you have not assigned the type of `customer` or `customerViewModel`, but if you do something like this then you should get compile time error:

```
const customer:Customer = new Customer();
let customerViewModel:CustomerLayoutViewModel = new CustomerLayoutViewModel();

customerViewModel  = customer;
```

Comment: Not true ..the type of the variable is inferred based on the assignment ..